# Export summary from python (spreg -pysal) to latex

Tags: python, latex, export, pysal

I did a SARAR spatial regression of the pysal spreg library (spreg.GM_Combo).

```
def reg_spatial(dep_var, independ_var): 
    m2 = spreg.GM_Combo(
    # Dependent variable
    pgdf[[dep_var]].values,
    pgdf[independ_var].values,
    w=w_queen,
    name_y=dep_var,
    name_x= independ_var,
) #SARAR Model

    return m2
```

```
mA = reg_spatial(dep_var, independ_var_A)
print(reg_spatial(dep_var, independ_var_A).summary)
```

[Ourput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff5mL.png)

I would like to export the summary in latex but the summary format is in str form and therefore does not have an as_latex() attribute. Do you have any idea how to get the summary in latex? Thank you very much in advance!